# Передача артефактов между пайплайнами

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner

Можно ли передать между двумя пайплайнами артефакты? Точнее мне нужно передать переменную. Т.е. не в рамках одного пайплайна, а между двумя пайплайнами

Есть 2 стадии: build, test. Но push выполняется уже после мерджа. Это обусловлено тем, что образ уезжает в реджистри только после ревью и мёрджа в мастер.

Answer (score 0):

Можно их через REST API вытаскивать, если знаешь номер пайплайна

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#list-pipeline-jobs

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html

---

### SHA из последнего пайплайна для некоторой ветки

`jq` утилита для работы с JSON. Устанавливается отдельно. Для `alpine` - `apk add jq`

`sed -n 1p` - пайпобезопасный `head -1`

По умолчанию Гитлаб сортирует по `id desc`, поэтому отдельно сортировать выдачу `pipelines?ref=xxx` не надо.

```
# Ветка, последний успешный пайплайн которой, хотим найти
REF=AP-1
LATEST_SHA=$(curl -s -H "Private-Token: $TOKEN" $CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/pipelines?ref=$REF | jq '.[].sha' | sed -n 1p)
echo $LATEST_SHA
```

Код выше буквально возьмёт последний пайплайн для определённой ветки, даже если он завершился неудачно.

Если надо последний удачный, то надо организовавыть цикл по пайплайнам, запрашивать по одному по id и проверять статус.

---

Последний SHA для какой-то ветки, кстати, можно просто из гита взять

```
REF=AP-1
LATEST_SHA=$(git log -1 --pretty=%H origin/$REF)
```

Comment: Как узнать номер предыдущего пайплайна?

Comment: У Гитлаба нет понятия "предыдущий" пайплайн. Есть список пайплайнов, есть кое-какие фильтры (по хэшу, по ветке) чтобы искать в этом списке. На крайний случай можно перебирать все один за одним и проверять, но так, конечно, делать не стоит.

Comment: А что за переменная? Если это какое-то состояние проекта, то можно хранить её как переменную проекта, она автоматически будет инжектится во все пайплайны, и время от времени пайплайны могут писать в неё через API. У нас так реализовано состояние code freeze/unfreeze

Comment: Коммит. Он является суффиксом версии образа. Нужен для пуша в реджистри и передачи образа между раннерами.

Comment: Произошёл мёрдж в мастер из ветки AP-*. Как мне выцепить пайплайн, связанный с этой веткой, который собирался перед мёрджем (последний успешный)?

Comment: Добавил кое-какой код. Но на мой взгляд, ты переусложняешь. Просто построй имидж ещё раз в том пайплайне, который будет пушить и всё.